# Any way to get impossible-to-miss desktop notifications?

Tags: gnome-shell, notification

Ubuntu 18.04.  I have my google calendar giving me desktop notifications, but they're easy to miss when you're absorbed in whatever you're working on.

I would like calendar notifications to be so so obvious that I cannot possibly miss them.  Something like full-screen goes red, can only be dismissed by typing "yes" would be perfect.

Obviously I don't want this to be the case for every notification (e.g Slack).

Is there some way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you consider audible notifications? `espeak` is a simple but good enough text-to-voice tool, that can tell you loudly, what you need to know. Anyway, espeak as well as painting the screen red can be scheduled via `crontab` with a time resolution of one minute.

Comment: Thing about audible is it's easy to miss if my volume is muted or I have headphones plugged in that I'm not wearing or I walk out of the room for a minute.  What I really need is something that does not allow you to continue working until you actively have dismissed the notification.

Comment: I don't use Google Calendar,so I don't know how to make it trigger something else than its own notification in the computer. But I know [**crontab**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) a classic tool in Linux, and it can run several commands, for example a tweaked `xterm` command. If you want to go that way, I can help. Otherwise, if you want to use Google Calendar, let us hope somebody who knows it will chip in and help you.